# Firebase Remote Config, "AND condition" with user in random percentile

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-remote-config

I want to define the following condition in firebase remote config, send parameter X to 10% of the users who speaks english, i.e. take the group of users who speak english, and from this group, select 10% of the users and send them a parameter.
is this the right way to do it?

[image]

Comment: This seems correct, mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Yes, this is the correct way to do it!

Comment: Good to know from an official source! :D Hey @steve-wilber is there some Firebase documentation or reference stating that directly (maybe even showing examples)? I was discussing this question with a coworker and this stackoverflow answer was the only piece of information we found confirming this behavior.

Comment: This is our [documentation on conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters). Although I'm not sure that would entirely answer the question above about how those conditions intersect. Thanks for the feedback, I'll see if we can add more.